# jQuery image in table data full screen when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have image in my table. 
I've tried use jQuery to popup modal fullscreen image.
But it just can at the top of table data

This my code

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['tanggal_komplain'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['nama_komplainer'];?><?php echo $d['pembuat'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['departemen_tujuan'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['personil_tujuan'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['subject'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['isi_komplain'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['status'];?></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center perbesar">
      <a href="#" id="pop">
        <img id="imageresource" src="image/<?php echo $d['nama_gambar']; ?>" width="80" height="80">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>    
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image preview</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#pop").on("click", function() {
   $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('src')); // here asign the image to the modal when the user click the enlarge link
   $('#imagemodal').modal('show'); // imagemodal is the id attribute assigned to the bootstrap modal, then i use the show function
});
</script>
```

hope someone can help me :((

Comment: add `type=button` in `pop` link...`<a  type="button" id="pop">`

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` to disable `a` link

```
`$("#pop").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('src')); // here     asign the image to the modal when the user click the enlarge link
 $('#imagemodal').modal('show'); // imagemodal is the id attribute assigned      to the bootstrap modal, then i use the show function
 });`
```

(or)

remove `href` and add `type=button` in `pop` link...`<a type="button" id="pop">...</a>`